# rpm --verify does not inform about missing file

Tags: linux, rpm

I noticed there is a missing file in the MySQL installation in a RHEL server. I want to know if there are more missing files so I tried to use `rpm --verify` (or `rpm -V`), however it doesn't output anything, even for the file that I know for sure that is missing:

```
# rpm -V  package  | grep my.cnf
# rpm -vV package  | grep my.cnf
# ls -l /etc/my.cnf
ls: cannot access /etc/my.cnf: No such file or directory
```

But that package does contain that file:

```
# rpm -ql package  | grep my.cnf
/etc/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/my.cnf` would be part of the package `mysql-libs`, or `mariadb-libs`, depending on the release (not something named *"package"*).  A verify on *that* package will show if it is missing, e.g.,

```
$ rpm -V mysql-libs
missing   c /etc/my.cnf
```

Incidentally, the verification shows that it is a configuration file.

Further reading (the files contained in the package are listed, for reference):

- [RHEL7 package](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/7.2.1511/x86_64/Packages/mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.centos.i686.html) (mariadb-libs)
- [RHEL6 package](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/remi/enterprise/6/x86_64/mysql-libs-5.5.50-1.el6.remi.x86_64.html) (mysql-libs)